# Splitting a string by 4 chars in c++

Tags: c++, split, binary, hex

i have a question regarding splitting a string. I am working on creating a binary to Hex converter, and want to split up my binary sequence that is represented as a string by 4 chars so that I can easily convert each set of 4 bits into a hexadecimal form:

Example:

```
00000111010110111100110100010101
```

would turn into:

```
"0000", "0111", "0101", "1011", "1100", "1101", "0001", "0101"
```

Thank you for any assistance you can provide!

Comment: `for` loop and `substr` seems like a nice simple starting point

Comment: @pm100 thanks ill try that

Comment: Would it be possible to convert the string into a char array of size [n][4]?

Comment: Maybe, have a look at String Class for more help and examples - [http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `std::string::substr` function and a simple for loop you can just sub-divide the string into groups of 4 and push them into a  `std::vector<std::string>` as shown below...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

int main() {
    std::string nums = "00000111010110111100110100010101";
    std::vector<std::string> bins;

    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < nums.size(); i += 4)
        bins.push_back(nums.substr(i, 4));

    return 0;
}
```

Then `bins` becomes a `std::vector` filled with the sub-divided binary numbers.